# Ways in relations not found when importing data to Overpass API

Tags: overpass-api

When importing region data into my local instance of Overpass API DB

bin/init_osm3s.sh slaskie-latest.osm.bz2 "db/" "binaries/" --meta

I got a ton of warnings like

```
compute_geometry: Way 539932453 used in relation 10072392 not found.
```

Although the whole operation completed successfully

```
Flushing to database ....... done.
Update complete.
```

Is it because the region data contains relation using way that lays outside of this region?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because the region data contains relation using way that lays outside of this region?

Those messages are normal for extracts. It's as you say, the extract lacks some relation members, and those messages hint towards that missing data.